# Tilix terminal as default on EOS 5.0 juno

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-terminal

How to set tilix terminal as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `dconf editor` from the application list

Browse to `org/gnome/desktop/applications/terminal/exec`

Uncheck `Use default value`

Type `tilix` as a custom value

Click the check mark in the bottom right of the window.

[image]

Now browse to `org/gnome/desktop/applications/terminal/exec-args` (one level up from 'exec')

Uncheck `Use default value`

Remove the `-e` from the custom value

Click the check mark in the bottom right side of the Window.

You're Done!

Comment: Works like a charm.  Should I be worried about the **DEPRECATED warning** in the description?  I initially did not try modifying this due to the warning.